# angularjs adding float labels

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add [floatlabels](http://clubdesign.github.io/floatlabels.js/) to my project, and I have added the floatlabel.js and jQuery files and references to the project, but when I try to initialize it with:

```
<script>
$('input.floatlabel').floatlabel();
</script>
```

It gives the error: 'the object doesn't support the method floatlabel'. I have also tried this:

```
<script>
  $(function(){ // document.ready
    $('input.floatlabel').floatlabel();
  });
</script>
```

What am I missing?

As someone pointed out, it's not an angular question, well that proves how confused I am, since I thought it was for angular, turns out, it's not. but this [float-label](https://github.com/chrisronline/angular-float-labels) is, and it works perfectly, sorry for my blunder.

Comment: Did you include the floatlabel js after jquery ?

Comment: yes I did, should that matter though?

Comment: What do you see in your browser development tools? Any errors or warnings in the console?

Comment: Currently floatlabels.js is dependant from jQuery 1.8+. Lower Versions have not been tested.

What is your version of jQuery?

Comment: In my console I only see 'the object doesn't support the method floatlabel', I have the latest jQuery version

Comment: is there maybe another way to initialize it that I can try?

Comment: could you to create a jsbin to show your code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that you are using correct version of the jquery for the floatlabels js . And you also have to load it after the loaded jquery . 
And after that you can initialize the script .